# MYSQL - PHP user login system not displaying individual crops for each user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm attempting to develop a user login system using PHP, where each user is assigned their own table within a database named 'crop'. However, despite each user having their own table, all users are seeing the same 'last crop'. How can I fix this issue?

here is the code:

```
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

CREATE TABLE `crop` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `qty` INT NOT NULL,
    `pot_size` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `thc` INT NOT NULL,
    `yield` INT NOT NULL,
    `ready` INT NOT NULL,
    `genetics` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `soil` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `startdate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `enddate` DATE NOT NULL,
    `total_harvested` INT NOT NULL,
    `strain_rating` INT DEFAULT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `user_crop` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `crop_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `crop_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`crop_id`) REFERENCES `crop` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE `watering` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `crop_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `ph` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `root_juice` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `bio_grow` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `bio_bloom` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `top_max` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `bio_heaven` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `acti_vera` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `wdate` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`crop_id`) REFERENCES `crop` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE `weather` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `temperature` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `humidity` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL);
```

And the PHP to create new crop:

```
<?php include 'include/dbconnect.php';?>
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['datepicker']) && isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] =='Submit' ){
    $originalDate = $_POST['datepicker'];
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $pot_size = $_POST['pot_size'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $soil = $_POST['soil'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $thc = $_POST['thc'];
    $yield = $_POST['yield'];
    $ready = $_POST['ready'];
    $genetics = $_POST['genetics'];
    $datepicker = $newDate;

    // SQL query to insert a new crop
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `crop` (`qty`,`pot_size`,`name`,`soil`,`type`,`thc`,`yield`,`ready`,`genetics`,`startdate`) VALUES ('$qty','$pot_size','$name','$soil','$type','$thc','$yield','$ready','$genetics','$datepicker')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New crop record created successfully";
        $crop_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

        // SQL query to associate the crop with the current user
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_crop` (`user_id`, `crop_id`) VALUES ('$user_id', '$crop_id')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "Crop associated with user successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: I understand this but it's only for local use not to be online at all, and I do not have the knowledge to make it safe but rather struggle with making it work :D

Comment: There is no valid justification for writing code vulnerable to SQL injections.  it's not hard to use prepared statements.  Dharman gave you a bunch of useful llinks.  Its not about whether your site will be online.  It's about doing LAMP development right.

Comment: "each user is assigned their own table within a database named 'crop'" this design is ill advised.

Comment: `I do not have the knowledge to make it safe`....it's actually _easier_ to do it  the safe way, than to give yourself extra problems by doing it badly. It's not just about security either, it also protects you from silly problems like un-escaped quote marks causing SQL syntax errors..etc. And you shouldn't get into bad habits...learn to do things properly from day 1. Then you don't have to re-learn anything later.

Comment: @erik258 true, but if you look at the various create table statements, you'll see that that's not actually what the OP has done. The table design looks sensible...they've just described it badly.

Comment: `all users are seeing the same 'last crop'`...it's not clear how you are defining "last crop", or what code you are using to calculate and display that information to the users. You've only shown code which inserts data rather than displaying it. Please provide a [mre] of that specific issue if you need assistance with it. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. `else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }` is also a bad design. It's verbose, makes your code harder to read, and would also be insecure to show errors on-screen in an internet-facing site (they should always be logged to a file). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die for an up-to-date, quicker, cleaner and more secure alternative way to trace mysqli errors.

Comment: P.P.S. https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli has some nice simple usage examples of prepared statements, if you don't like the info in the official PHP documentation (it can be a bit confusing to follow in places, or at least a bit disparate compared to a tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the comments.

@Dharman - SQL Injections, not so hard to fix ... turned out :D

Fixed code:

```
    // Enable error reporting and logging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/php_errors.log');

// Initialize the session if it hasn't been started already
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Validate and sanitize the user inputs
$qty = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qty', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$pot_size = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pot_size', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$soil = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'soil', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$type = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$thc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'thc', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$yield = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'yield', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$ready = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ready', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$genetics = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'genetics', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$datepicker = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'datepicker', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// SQL query to insert a new crop
$sql = "INSERT INTO `crop` (`qty`, `pot_size`, `name`, `soil`, `type`, `thc`, `yield`, `ready`, `genetics`, `startdate`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iisssiiiss', $qty, $pot_size, $name, $soil, $type, $thc, $yield, $ready, $genetics, $datepicker);
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "New crop record created successfully";
    $crop_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    // SQL query to associate the crop with the current user
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_crop` (`user_id`, `crop_id`) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $user_id, $crop_id);
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        echo "Crop associated with user successfully<br>";
    } else {
        $error_msg = "Error associating crop with user: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        error_log($error_msg);
        echo "Error associating crop with user";
    }
} else {
    $error_msg = "Error creating new crop record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    error_log($error_msg);
    echo "Error creating new crop record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
 }
}
```

@ADyson -

> ...it's not clear how you are defining "last crop", or what code you
> are using to calculate and display that information to the users.

You were very right here! I did not think that I must look at the way I present the data to each user.
My approach:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$fetchqry = "SELECT c.*, DATE_FORMAT(c.startdate, ' %d/%m/%Y') AS startdate  
             FROM crop c
             JOIN user_crop uc ON c.id = uc.crop_id
             WHERE uc.user_id = $user_id
             ORDER BY c.id DESC 
             LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchqry);

if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
} else {
    // handle case where no crop is found for the current user
}
?>
```

All this sorted my problems. For now :)
Thank you All!